# How can I read a default value using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So my first task is that i had to make an input field and it's default value has to be "blue".

First problem is that I'm not sure if I did this part right.

My second task to make the second button read the value of the input field and change all my buttons background color to that color.

[image: Here's my HTML code for it]

[image: Here's my Javascript code for it]

What did I do wrong?
(U don't have to worry about the Test1 and Test2 buttons they're working fine)

```
    
$('#color').value = 'blue';


$('#button1').on('click', () => {
    console.log('U just clicked Test1')
    $('#button1').text("Teszt");
    
  });
  $('#button2').on('click', () => {
    $('#button1').text("Hey");
  });
  $('#button3').on('click', () => {
      $('button').css('background','$('#color').text()')

  });
```

Comment: Please include the code as text (Also, VSCode is highlighting the error...)

Comment: Please provide your code in text form and not as a screen shot. That makes quoting easier. Nobody here will write down the code from your screenshots

Answer (score 2):

To Write data from a variable in string you can use `${variable}` (these accents used in french and spanish)

so

```
$('button').css('background-color', `${$('#color').val()}`)
```

The other option you have is to just use the return value.

```
$('button').css('background-color', $('#color').val())
```

So no quotes needed

But you should consider the case when someone is typing something that is not a color, like Foo or so.
Setting the color should be more deterministic.

Comment: Something si still not right. It doesn't do anything but at least it's not an error now

Comment: use .val() instead of .text() and it should work. (Edited my post)

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<body>
  <input type="text" value="blue" id="color">
  <button class="button" id="button1">Test 1</button>
  <button class="button" id="button2">Test 1</button>
  <button class="button" id="button3">Test 1</button>
</body>
```

jQuery :
Get value of input field using `.val()` method

```
$("button").css("background-color", $("#color").val());
```